# aws lambda import error even i have install all the packages

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am geting error with paramiko library in lambda aws

```
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 3, in lambda_handler
    import paramiko
  File "/var/task/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 90, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "/var/task/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/var/task/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _bcrypt
ImportError: libffi-45372312.so.6.0.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

END RequestId: 93798bf6-532a-4cda-bdba-6bc858ce97ae
REPORT RequestId: 93798bf6-532a-4cda-bdba-6bc858ce97ae  Duration: 46.77 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1600 MB    Max Memory Used: 55 MB  Init Duration: 68.02 ms
```

event this package is install i have 4 months ago and this run very successfully on lambda now same function creating problem

Comment: i have already install this

Answer (score 1):

when create a zip then use this command

```
sudo zip -r ./x.zip .
```

it will create a zip with hide folders and files

I was using this command that way it is not working

```
 #wrong command this is 
 sudo zip -r ./x.zip *
```

[Import Error from cyptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963857/import-error-from-cyptography-hazmat-bindings-constant-time-import-lib)